# Мой проект из unity не работает на Android 11. Что мне делать?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Всем привет! У меня есть игра, сделанная в unity, которая стабильно работает на android ниже 11 версии. Испытывал ее на смартфонах. Но когда в unity нажимаю "build and run" и выбираю эмулятор из Android Studio с android 11, игра работает некорректно (скриншоты [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdnZt.jpg) и [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrtR6.jpg)), более того, когда я пытаюсь скачать тестовую версию через Google Play, там вылезает сообщение, что игра несовместима с моим устройством (скриншот [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0iQp.jpg)). Хотя у меня выбран "Target API Level Android 11 (API Level 30)" и в google play console он отображается (скриншот [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpZrk.jpg)). Причем у меня не появилось никаких проблем, когда я устанавливал рандомные игры из google play на эмулятор (некоторые из них сделаны с помощью unity).

Я уже пробовал устанавливать sdk 30 через unity и через android studio. Пробовал через разные версии unity: 2021.1.12f1, 2020.3.12f1, 2020.106f1. Переустанавливал unity и android studio. И ничего не помогло.

Вот некоторые мои настройки (скриншот [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srm7W.jpg) и [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCXAe.jpg)).

Буду очень вам признателен, если поможете мне разобраться с этой проблемой!

Comment: На телефоне с 11 Андрюшей проверяли?

Comment: На телефоне с 11 андроидом не проверял, но проверял на телефонах с 7,8, и 9 андроидом, все исправно работает. Самое интересное то, что на эмулятор с 11 андроидом могу установить любое приложение из гугл плея, причем одно из них было точно сделано с помощью юнити (там была их начальная картинка)

Comment: Пока не проверите на телефоне, рано что-либо утверждать.

Comment: Похоже на то, что проблемы рендерингом, возможно эмулируемый видеочип не совместим с требованиями unity. Действительно, нужно тестировать на физическом устройстве, прежде, чем что то радикальное предпринимать. В любом случае, это проблема "железа" скорее всего

Comment: @aepot, спасибо вам за ответ, буду пытаться найти устройство на 11 андроиде. Но не дает покоя то, что другие игры сделанные на юнити могу скачать на эмулятор, и они исправно работают. Вот что вспомнил: мне оставили отзыв с устройства на 11 андроиде, что игра зависает при запуске, но что-то мне подсказывает, что человек даже не смог его установить... (не смог прикрепить скриншот с подтверждением сюда)

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо вам за ответ, буду пытаться найти устройство на 11 андроиде. Но не дает покоя то, что другие игры сделанные на юнити могу скачать на эмулятор, и они исправно работают. Вот что вспомнил: мне оставили отзыв с устройства на 11 андроиде, что игра зависает при запуске, но что-то мне подсказывает, что человек даже не смог его установить... (не смог прикрепить скриншот с подтверждением сюда)